# Can't compare HashMap key value to Scanner input

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to compare a key value from a `HashMap` to an index of an array generated from user input.  The overall goal is to turn 12/25/2000 into December 25, 2000, and everything else works except for this.

```
import java.util.*;

class Dates {

private static final Set<Integer> THIRTY_DAY_MONTHS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 6, 8, 11));
private static Map<Integer, String> MONTHS = new HashMap<>(12);
private static String monthString;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter month/day/year to be converted to normal format: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] input = s.nextLine().split("/");

        int[] inputNumbers = new int[input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            inputNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
        }

        int month = inputNumbers[0];
        int day = inputNumbers[1];
        int year = inputNumbers[2];

        MONTHS.put(1, "January");
        MONTHS.put(2, "February");
        MONTHS.put(3, "March");
        MONTHS.put(4, "April");
        MONTHS.put(5, "May");
        MONTHS.put(6, "June");
        MONTHS.put(7, "July");
        MONTHS.put(8, "August");
        MONTHS.put(9, "September");
        MONTHS.put(10, "October");
        MONTHS.put(11, "November");
        MONTHS.put(12, "December");

        for(Integer currentKey : MONTHS.keySet()) {
            if (currentKey == month)
                monthString = MONTHS.get(currentKey);
            else
                throw new MonthException();
        }

        if (THIRTY_DAY_MONTHS.contains(month) && day > 30) { //Logic for valid day ranges for months that only contain 30 days
            throw new DayException();
        } else if (day > 31 || day <= 0) { //Logic for max and min # of possible days per any month
            throw new DayException();
        } else if (month == 2 && day > 29 && year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) { //Logic for # of days in February for a leap year
            throw new DayException();
        } else if (year < 1000 || year > 3000) { //Logic for valid range of years
            throw new YearException();
        }

        System.out.println(monthString + ' ' + day + ", " + year);


    } catch (MonthException | DayException | YearException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I split something like 12/25/2000 into integers 12, 25, and 2000, and set those to `month`, `day`, and `year`.  But when I try to compare the `currentKey` to the month value, it always throws a `MonthException`, and I'm not sure why.  I tried using `entrySet` to get both the keys and the values, but I get the same result.

What I want to happen is the loop iterates until `currentKey` equals the `month` inputted, and then sets `monthString` to the value at that key.

Comment: Please provide runnable code.

Comment: Obvious solution: Get rid of the else block. If you walk through your program code mentally it should be obvious why this is causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace the for loop with

```
monthString = MONTHS.get(month);
if (monthString == null) {
    throw new MonthException();
}
```

in which then monthString would be null triggering the MonthException if the key was not found in the Map.

Comment: Oh I'm insanely dumb, got so focused on looping through the map that I forgot you can just do this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code

```
for(Integer currentKey : MONTHS.keySet()) {
    if (currentKey == month) // this line may cause the problem
        monthString = MONTHS.get(currentKey);
    else
        throw new MonthException();
}
```

You should use

```
if(currentKey.equals(month))
```

Why you need to `for` loop here?

You can just use

```
monthString = MONTHS.get(month);
```

now if `monthString=null` you can throw your exception.

```
monthString = MONTHS.get(month);
if (monthString == null) {
 throw new MonthException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the else block runs on the first iteration if the predicate fails. you want to throw the exception only after you have looped thru the entire map.

```
for(Integer currentKey : MONTHS.keySet()) {
    if (currentKey == month) {
        monthString = MONTHS.get(currentKey);
        break;
    }
    else if (currentKey != month && currentKey == 12)
        throw new MonthException();
}
```

Comment: if you'd throw the exception only after the loop, you'd avoid the hardcoded "currentKey = 12" check. Also, you have there an assignment, not a comparison...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop a Map which is slow is Map is large.
You can use containsKey method like this which is fast:

```
    if(MONTHS.containsKey(month))
    {
        monthString = MONTHS.get(month);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new MonthException();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you throws the exception , which breaks the loop;

Change you code , and add the throws clause after the loop like this...

```
   /**      after you code...  **/
    boolean notfound=true;
    for (Integer currentKey : MONTHS.keySet()) {
        String monthString;
        System.out.println("test.main()"+currentKey+month);
        if (currentKey.equals(month)){
         monthString = MONTHS.get(currentKey);
         notfound=false;


    }

}
    if(notfound)            
        throw new Exception();
```